# How do I break out of a loop sequence only for one item of the loop, continuing to loop the other items?

Tags: c#, foreach, return, break

I have a loop (see below). If I enter any of the catch blocks, I want to end the loop for the item I'm looping at the moment (I have an array of file paths).

Say the item is file = "C:\test.txt"

When looping this file (C:\test.txt), if something goes wrong, I want to halt the loop for this file BUT continue the foreach for the other files in the array finalFiles.

Is this possible?

```
foreach (string file in finalFiles)
{
                if (file.Contains(".tiff") == true)
                {
                    PolicyNumber = Path.GetFileName(file).Split('_')[0];
                    basePolicyNumber = PolicyNumber.Remove(PolicyNumber.Length - 2);
                    basePolicyNumber = basePolicyNumber + "00";

                    finalPolicyName = Path.GetFileName(file);

                    try
                    {
                        PolicyUUID = Transporter.GetPolicyUUID(AppVars.pxCentralRootURL, basePolicyNumber);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error getting UUID from policy online!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        uploadToPxCentralWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                    }

                    ixLibrarySourceFileURL = AppVars.ixLibraryPolicyAttachmentsURL + finalPolicyName;

                    try
                    {
                        Transporter.UploadFileToixLibrary(AppVars.ixLibraryPolicyAttachmentsURL, file);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        uploadToPxCentralWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                        error = 1;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Call `continue;`

Comment: ahhhhhh, i was not aware of this keyword! thanks! :) .. i'll give it a try!

Comment: [Here are the docs for `continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How about continue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [continue keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It will continue the loop at the next iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "continue" keyword for these situations.

MSDN link to the usage is [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`continue keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
foreach (string file in finalFiles)
{
   if(bad condition)
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the continue statment.

[Continue Statment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @ViralShah and that was necessary because?